# Xoti's lantern and ghosts interaction

Tags: pillars-of-eternity-ii

Spoilers for first hour of the game (and not much more, since that's about how much I played).

So, In this game there seems to be the concept of finding the souls of dead people stuck in the world, and somehow "guiding them" - which so far meant doing a conversation, asking them to follow you and they disappear.

However, after getting Xoti as a companion she has a special interaction - instead of asking them to follow you, she does something with her lantern. Souls encountered that way get added to the description of the lantern which suggests it's important.

Does she get to do that to the souls I already met before and told to follow me (the two on the beach you land on)? What's the difference between having her do that and just talking to ghost and having them "follow you"?

Comment: I'm pretty much in the same istuation as you. I think, it'll be a couple days before anyone can answer this, as the lantern likely plays an integral part in Xotis quest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make a gameplay difference whether a soul follows you or is put in the lantern.

Lorewise, if a soul follows you, it returns to the wheel after you visit an active Adra Pillar. If it's put into Xotis lantern it is released by whatever method you chose for xoti at the end of her companion quest.

The number of souls in her lantern are only relevant once, namely, you need to get enough souls in there to trigger the quest continuation (around 10). There are enough wayward souls on Port Maje alone to trigger this.

Comment: How can there be enough souls on Port Maje alone, if there are only 3 of them on the first island? Do groups (like the multitude of them at the digsite after repairing the pillar) count as more then one?